# Divide a Count by Count in a query and upsert to new table

Tags: kdb

Given a table, I would like to get the **ratio** between rows that are `removed` and `approved` by company, delimited by a certain range (amount).

**Sample Table**

```
status   company amount
-----------------------
removed  a       100   
removed  b       200   
approved b       300   
removed  a       400   
approved b       500   
removed  b       600   
approved b       700   
removed  a       800
approved a       900   
removed  a       1000
```

**A Malformed Query:**

```
update sample: count Status where (Status = `approved) % count Status where (Status = `removed) where (amount<= 500, amount > 0) by company from sample

update sample: count Status where (Status = `approved) % count Status where (Status = `removed) where (amount<= 1000, amount > 500) by company from sample
```

**Resultant Table**

```
company  0-500  600-1000
-----------------------
  a       0       1/2
  b       2       1
```

- **A** has two `removed` deals in the 0 - 500 range, hence its ratio is **0**.
- **B** has two `approved` deals and one `removed` deal in the 0 - 500 range, hence its ratio is **2**.
- **A** has one `approved` deal and two `removed` deals in the 600 - 1000 range, hence its ratio is **1/2**.
- **B** has one `approved and one`removed` deal in the 600 - 1000 range, hence its ratio is **1**.

**Table Query**

```
sample:([]status:`removed`removed`approved`removed`approved`removed`approved`removed`approved`removed; company:`a`b`b`a`b`b`b`a`a`a; amount: 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000)
```

Comment: To help others, can you include the code that generates your sample table. Thanks.

Comment: Yes of course, thanks for reminding.

Comment: I think the "Table Query" is not in sync with your example. E.g. amounts 900 and 1000 are missing.

Comment: It is still wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One potential way of achieving your specifications would be to form two select queries and horizontally joining them.

```
q)a:select range1:(count status where status=`approved)%count status where status=`removed by company from sample where amount within (0;500)
q)b:select range2:(count status where status=`approved)%count status where status=`removed by company from sample where amount within (600;1000)
q)a ,' b
company| range1 range2
-------| -------------
a      | 0      0.5
b      | 2      1
```

Additionally you can rename the columns so that their names are as you wanted in your question:

```
q)(`company,(`$"0-500"),(`$"600-1000")) xcol a,'b
company| 0-500 600-1000
-------| --------------
a      | 0     0.5
b      | 2     1
```

The following will give you the answer you requested, however it does require you to be looking within the ranges of 0-600 and 600-1200, as `xbar` will split the amount column into chunks within multiples of 600. The above is more specific to your request (i.e. 0-500 and 600-1000).

```
q)ratios:select (sum status=`approved)%sum status=`removed by company,600 xbar amount from sample
q)ratios
company amount| x
--------------| ---
a       0     | 0
a       600   | 0.5
b       0     | 2
b       600   | 1
```

The table can then be pivoted to give the required table format:

```
q)exec ((`$"0-600"),(`$"600-1200"))!x by company:company from ratios
company| 0-600 600-1200
-------| --------------
a      | 0     0.5
b      | 2     1
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I created the random sample table with:

```
n:100;t:([]status:n?`a`r;company:n?`a`b`c`d;amount:100*n?10)
status company amount
---------------------
r      a       800
r      c       100
a      c       900
a      d       500
a      a       400
a      a       600
a      a       600
r      c       100
r      c       800
a      a       500
r      c       400
r      a       900
r      d       200
r      c       700
a      a       0
r      b       100
a      c       900
a      d       200
a      a       100
a      d       800
```

Then, I created a dictionary with different sized ranges where the values are the lower bounds:

```
g:`g1`g2`g3`g4!0 200 300 500
```

Next, I used `bin` here to get the ratios that fall within each bucket range:

```
q)select rat:sum[status=`a]%sum[status=`r] by company , amount:key[g] value[g] bin amount from t
company amount| rat
--------------| ---------
a       g1    | 1.666667
a       g2    | 0w
a       g3    | 0w
a       g4    | 0.6666667
b       g1    | 1
b       g2    | 1
b       g3    | 1.5
b       g4    | 1.333333
c       g1    | 0.3333333
c       g2    | 2
c       g3    | 0.3333333
c       g4    | 0.875
d       g1    | 0.6666667
d       g2    | 3
d       g3    | 3
d       g4    | 5
```

Finally, I used a pivot on the whole thing to visualize the data better:

```
q){[x] exec  key[g]#amount!rat by company:company from x}  select rat:sum[status=`a]%sum[status=`r] by company , amount:key[g] value[g] bin amount from t
company| g1        g2 g3        g4
-------| --------------------------------
a      | 1.666667  0w 0w        0.6666667
b      | 1         1  1.5       1.333333
c      | 0.3333333 2  0.3333333 0.875
d      | 0.6666667 3  3         5
```

Comment: You can simplify the range dictionary piece by applying the sorted attribute as described in [Q for Mortals](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#881-sorted-s).

When you define `g` with the amounts as the key and apply the sorted attribute the dictionary automatically uses `bin` for lookup, effectively turning `g` into a step function:
`g:\`s#0 200 300 500!\`g1\`g2\`g3\`g4`.

Then your final query can be simplified to
`select rat:sum[status=\`a]%sum[status=\`r] by company , g amount from t`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 2 step process:

Step 1: Calculate the ratio by company and amount range.

```
q)t:([]status:`removed`removed`approved`removed`approved`removed`approved`removed`approved`removed;company:`a`b`b`a`b`b`b`a`a`a;amount:100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000)

q) r:select   ratio:((%) . sum@'status=/:`approved`removed) by company, range:(`s#(0 600)!`0`600) amount from t
```

Here first I am dividing the amount into buckets using a sorted dictionary. The sorted dictionary works as a step function.

After that, it is just calculating the ratio by company and bucket.

```
Output

company range| ratio
-------------| -----
a       0    | 0    
a       600  | 0.5  
b       0    | 2    
b       600  | 1
```

It calculates the required result. Now we have to convert this output to the output you want which is a Pivot Table.

Step 2: [Pivot Table](https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/pivoting-tables/)
This step will convert the last result into the table output you want.

```
q) P:asc exec distinct range from r
q) exec P#(range!ratio) by company:company from r
```

```
Output

company| 0 600
-------| -----
a      | 0 0.5
b      | 2 1
```

You can change the column names you want in the sorted dictionary which is used in step 1.

Also if there is no `removed` entry for any bucket range then ration will be `0w`. If you want to use any other values for such cases then that you can handle that in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would get that stats, then I could do column renaming and finally do a pivot. For bucketing people use xbar, but in your case, you need binr to include upper threshold.

```
thresholds: 500 1000
rename: 0 1!`$("0-500"; "500-1000")
temp: select r: (sum status = `approved ) % (sum status = `removed) by company, bucket: rename thresholds binr amount from sample
exec value[rename]#(bucket!r) by company:company from temp
```

To get pivot table, I recommend reading this:
https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/pivoting-tables/